# Windows 7 Key not working

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a genuine Windows 7 Home Premium key and it does not want to work. It is of a OEM laptop and is being reinstalled on the the same OEM laptop. Why is it not letting me activate? Thanks

Comment: Not even by phone?

Comment: Doesn't even give me the option. Or at least I haven't seen it.

Comment: Windows should automatically try to activate after a couple days, at which point it should tell you that it can't and give you options on how you can activate it.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't want to work"? Are you getting an error message stating the activation failed? Are you connected to the Internet?

Comment: @ CharlieRB It says "The product key you have enetered does not appear to be a valid Windows 7 Product key, please check your product key, and type it again."